# Product of polynomials made from the subarray of an array

Tags: algorithm, math

We are given an array of coefficients and we need to find the product of all the polynomials which we can create using all the subarray of the given array.

I am able to solve it in O(n^2) complexity. But i want to improve the complexity of the program.
The polynomials are created in the following manner.

Example array :- [2, 4, 1]
Now all subarrays of this array are as follows :-

```
[2]        -> 2x^0
[2, 4]     -> 2x^0 + 4x^1
[2, 4, 1]  -> 2x^0 + 4x^1 + 1x^2
[4]        -> 4x^0
[4, 1]     -> 4x^0 + 1x^1
[1]        -> 1x^0
```

And now i need the product of all the polynomials.
I tried solving it for array of length 3 but i failed to find the pattern. Here is the screenshot of the my work.

[An attempt to find some pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K5SO.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder how you can do this in `O(n^2)` time when output size is `O(n^3)`.

Comment: We are given a value of x so we can use prefix sums.

Comment: http://algorithm.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~course/Extra_Info/Divide%20and%20Conquer_supplement.pdf
There is an O(n^lg3) algorithm there.

Comment: Can also use FFT: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fast-fourier-transformation-poynomial-multiplication/

Comment: I think OP is talking about multiplying n*n subarrays. But FFT is used to multiply two polynomials. Isn't it n^3 log n. @wcochran

Comment: @Ivanchuk The linked photo https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K5SO.jpg shows the OP multiplying polynomials. I guess the OP is a little vague.

Comment: You only need a value of the product at the particular `x`, right? If so, add it to the question, otherwise people get confused. Usually when we talk about the products of polynomials, we imply that we want a resulting polynomial. It is a very different problem.